# object error in ie7

Tags: internet-explorer-7

How can i solve object error in ie7. Once i load my page. ie7 shows `[object Error]` in an alert box. i want to know why it happens and how to solve this.

Comment: It's a bit difficult to answer this question in its current form. Could you provide the code which produces the error and maybe an example?

Comment: My code is very lengthy. so i cant. If i guess which part produce this alert i can post. but i dont know where it occurs

Comment: You will need to provide more details before anyone will be able to give you any help. As things stand we simply don't know enough to give a useful answer. If it's an alert box, just check that you don't have any calls to `alert()` in your js code that might be meant for debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(EDIT)* this just in:

It now seems that IE7 sometimes displays this popup when an error occurs. It almost looks like it's trying to display an `alert()` with an object in it, called `error`. Here's how I found out. I was trying to set a table row's CSS `display` attribute to `table-row`, but after some debugging and internet seaching, I found out that IE7 and earlier do not support `table-row` as a `display` value. What I had:

```
document.getElementById('writeoff_tablerow').style.display = 'table-row';
```

What solved the problem:

```
try {
    document.getElementById('writeoff_tablerow').style.display = 'table-row';
}
catch(e) {
    document.getElementById('writeoff_tablerow').style.display = 'block';
}
```

---

*(EARLIER ANSWER)*

I've been stumped with this same thing today. Ultimately, the cause of the problem boiled down to the fact that I was using document.body.addEventListener to make the page respond to a mouse click:

```
document.body.addEventListener('click',function(){document.getElementById('blah_div_id').style.display='none';},false);
```

When I changed the code to the following, the problem was gone in IE7:

```
document.body.onclick=function(){document.getElementById('blah_div_id').style.display='none';};
```

Answer (score 0):

post some code, otherwise we cant help you.

try the website in Firefox with Firebug installed, and maybe you will get additional information in the console there (if the problem is in FF as well, that is)

Answer (score 0):

**Since i am using Protovis Graph library. This is cause for my error. Since Protovis is not compactable with ie7 it araise object error.**